# zend framework 2 : bootstrap file outside webroot

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, zend-framework2

I'm creating a zend framework 2 website and i want to create a few standalone php files (that use some of the Model objects) so i can put them in a cronjob. I also want to place them outside the webroot where they're not publicly accessible.

The problem is that none of the model objects are resolved .
I've included init_autoloader, but still i have to require all files explicitly.

Does some know how to create standalone bootstrap files in such a way that autoloading still works?

Comment: What I have done with ZF 1 projects is to copy the gateway script and omited the `->run()` off of the `$app->bootstrap()->run();`

Comment: I'm happy to confirm this works for ZF 2 projects too! :-)

I don't know how to mark a comment as the solution though....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change $app->bootstrap()->run() to $app->bootstrap() in the gateway (index.php)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is wondering what the complete solution looks like, here it is:

```
<?php
/**
 * in my case, the script was put in a subfolder of the project-root, called 'cron'
 * make sure you adjust this according to where you put it.
 */
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php');

/**
 * your code goes here
 */

echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s").": cron finished";
```